# how to use linq to return a value from 4 tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I am reasonably new to Linq and it seems quite easy to iuse but I am having an issue when trying to extract a value from a table that is linked/constrained by 3 other tables.

I have this in my SQL DB:

[image]

I am using Asp.Net 4 and Entity Framework 6.

I have as a parameter the 'DatabaseName'.

I ultimately want to get the SubscriptionRef that is assigned to this name.

I could do this step-by-step (ie using multiple linqs) but I thought it would look 'clean' using just 1 linq statment.

I have got as far as this:

```
var names = o.RegisteredNames.Where(d => d.DatabaseName == DBName).Where(d => d.ClientNames.Where(f => f.ClientId == f.Client.ClientId).FirstOrDefault();
```

But I get the error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Services.ClientName' to 'bool'
```

Comment: `.Where()` returns an IEnumerable containing elements which pass the clause. I think you might want to take a look at [`.Include()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Bas thanks - i will do so now

Comment: I would say doing this step-by-step is cleaner than just one huge statement. First it's easier to read and second it's easier to debug.

Comment: @ThomasSchneiter thanks a point worth considering. I now in a position where I need to know how to do this but may in the end do as u suggest :)

Comment: It would help, if we had your object models of Clients and Services.

Comment: @Nils Hi, but that is why I included the image of the tables. The Models map directly to this?

Comment: No, not neccessarily... depends on how you started... did you implement model first?

Comment: hi, no i did the database 1st :)

Comment: well ok - that explains the ClientNames table.. it sure looks like a classic many-to-many table. Entity framework usually does not use objects for these (when going code first)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130002/discussion-between-nils-and-andrew-simpson).

Answer (score 0):

You have a Problem here:

```
d => d.ClientNames.Where(f => f.ClientId == f.Client.ClientId)
```

`f => ...` returns a single `ClientName` or `null`, which causes your error, because there should be a boolean.
If you want this first value or null, you should replace

```
.Where(d => d.ClientNames ...
//with
.Select(d => d.ClientNames ...
```

Comment: Thanks I will test this. I need to fix a few bugs before I can publish so please bear with me :)

Comment: Hey that's ok - if it's not what you need let me know so i can delete the answer as it is not needed then

Comment: Hi, looking at this I still cannot see how to get the subscriptionRef?

Comment: If `subscriptionRef` is in your Clientname you should be able to get it by `.SubcriptionRef` behind the `.FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: The SubscriptionRef only appears in the tables Client and Subscription

Answer (score 0):

You can try with one `LINQ` query like...

```
var names = o.RegisteredNames.Where(d => d.DatabaseName == DBName ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks i need to fix a few bugs before i can publish and test :)

Comment: Its ok. but you can do like this also.. :)

Comment: did not compile? It tells me RegisteredName does not contain a definition for ClientId?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
o.RegisteredNames.First(d => d.DatabaseName == DBName).ClientNames.Select(x=>x.Client.Subscription.SubscriptionRef)
```

It should give you list go SubscriptionRef.

Comment: Thanks will get back to soon after publish/test

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna try sql style:

```
var client = from c in db.Clients 
  join cn in db.ClientNames on c.ClientId equals cn.ClientId 
  join rn in db.RegisteredNames on cn.RegisteredNamesId equals rn.RegisteredNameId 
  where rn.DatabaseName == "YourDBName"
  select c;
```

But it also depends on how your objects were built.

Comment: thanks i new i could do this but I wanted to see if I could avoid using joins and the intellisense using linq seemed to indicate

Answer (score 0):

Try using join:

```
var names  = (
           from names in o.RegisteredNames.Where(d => d.DatabaseName == DBName)
           join cnames in o.ClientNames on names.RegisteredNamesId equals cnames.RegisteredNamesId
           select cnames.ClientId
         ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Add as many joins as you want.

Comment: thanks i new i could do this but I wanted to see if I could avoid using joins and the intellisense using linq seemed to indicate

Answer (score 0):

Try this

It works in List,

```
var option1= o.RegisteredNames
                .Where(g => g.DbName == "YourDbName")
                .Where(h => h.ClientNames.Any(f => f == 5))
                .FirstOrDefault();

var option2= o.RegisteredNames
               .FirstOrDefault(h => h.DbName == "Name" && h.ClientNames.Any(j => j == 1));
```